# ¿Cómo guardo en una cadena esto?

Tags: c

Tengo esta función que imprime un número decimal en binario:

```
void decimalBinario(char n[], int b){
    unsigned char var = n;
    unsigned int i, inicio = pow(2,b-1); 

    for(i = inicio; i > 0; i >>= 1) 
        if(i & var)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
}
```

Pero ahora quiero guardar en una cadena o arreglo lo que imprime dicha función, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: ¿Seguro que esa función imprime el número `b` en binario?

Comment: Sí, la probé varias veces y funciona bien

Comment: Mira que lo dudo... `decimalBinario(n,10);` imprime `1111111111` cuando debería ser `1010` ...

Comment: Perdón el número que se quiere convertir entra en el primer parámetro, el segundo parámetro son la cantidad de varibles.
Anexo la liga de donde tomé el código: https://blog.nativehex.com/imprimir-binario-c

Comment: entonces no has intentado nada por tu cuenta?